# Use Javascript to create a space at the bottom of page for toolbar widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I am creating a toolbar widget that is loaded via an external javascript file. The toolbar floats at the bottom of the screen, which works fine, but the content at the bottom of the screen gets covered up (as seen in Figure A). Figure B is my goal.

The toolbar should always be visible, fixed to the bottom of the screen. If scrolling is needed on the page, the content will flow under it until it is all visible when scrolled all the way to the bottom, so that nothing gets covered up on any length page.

[image: Before and after examples]

My first thought was to set a bottom margin of 30px (toolbar height), but since most of the websites this is designed for are setup to use the full screen (with body height set to 100%), this won't always work. Decreasing the body scrollHeight by 30px fixes this issue, but only if scrolling isn't required on the page (which sometimes is).

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbMDr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a somewhat hacky solution I've come up with, that seems to work so far (I haven't done extensive testing yet). If anyone has a cleaner way of accomplishing this it would be interesting.

```
var bodyCH = document.body.clientHeight,
    bodySH = document.body.scrollHeight;

/* insert the toolbar here */

if (bodyCH === bodySH) {
    document.body.style.height = parseInt(bodySH, 10) - 30 + 'px';
} else {
    var spacer = document.createElement('div');
    spacer.style.height = '30px';
    document.body.appendChild(spacer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this example work for you? http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/footer

Comment: This is probably a stupid question - but why does body height need to be 100%? I thought that was a CSS trick for other footer implementations.

Comment: Right, I'm saying I don't have control over the websites because this is a widget that will be inserted into 3rd party sites, and several of them use 100% body height.